# Computing the nth Fibonacci number using linear recursion

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci, coding-efficiency

I have tried **binary recursion** to find the nth Fibonacci number (or the whole Fibonacci series by using a `for` loop in `main()`) but according to *Data Structures and Algorithms in Java* (6th Edition) by Michael T. Goodrich; it is a terribly inefficient method as it requires an exponential number of calls to the method. An efficient recursion technique is **linear recursion** given as follows;

```
/**Returns array containing the pair of Fibonacci numbers, F(n) and F(n-1)*/
public static long[] fibonacciGood(int n) {
    if(n<=1) {
        long[] answer = {n,0};
        return answer;
    }else {
        long[] temp = fibonacciGood(n-1);               //returns {F(n-1), F(n-2)
        long[] answer = {temp[0]+temp[1], temp[0]};     //we want {F(n), F(n-1)}
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the code it returns a reference as
[[J@15db9742](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcwPR.png)

which is not the desired answer. What should I write in `main()` so that i can have the desired answer?

Comment: Unrelated but since you are interested in efficiency here: also note that there is a simple closed form solution to any Fibonacci type sequence which doesn't require any loops or recursion at all.

Comment: I would really like to have a look. Pls share.

Comment: Please read the duplicate really carefully. You do not have a problem with recursion. Your problem is that you do not understand what System.out.println(someArray) does.If you look at the answer which you accepted here, and the accepted answer on the DUP question ... guess what: they say the same.

Comment: @EqraKhattak: [Wikipedia covers this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Generalizations) take a look at the section titled "Closed-form expression"

Comment: @GhostCat Sadly actually, I don't understand how this recursion method is called in main(). I don't know how it matters if the answer is same for a question on array. The context is totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the one below. You can refer the api [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(long[])).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibonacciGood(4)));
    }
```

Comment: That worked well for me. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print out an array to the console, this is causing the memory address of the array to be output. You may want to iterate through the array returned, printing every element to get the desired output.

Comment: It is not really the memory address though.

Comment: @GhostCat what reference is that?

Answer (score -1):

Here you are printing the array object, so you are getting these results. Internally it calls toString method of the object, which return `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`. So you are getting value as **[J@15db9742**.

You can use convert is directly as below (Working in Java version 5 and above)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibonacciGood(4)));
```

You can print it by converting it to list as below (in Java 8 or above) **(Not Preferable to use streams here, but just for knowledge)**:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(fibonacciGood(4)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: The first option is like super overkill. Thats like carving the numbers into granite plates, to then ship them around the globe, to then have a person read them to you on the phone ...

Comment: thanks a lot but I didn't understand your (java 8 or above) code. Can you pls explain it.

Comment: Please do not suggest the excessive and unnecessary use of streams.

Comment: @GhostCat you marked my Question as duplicate, i can't see why. The question u marked me duplicate to, is totally about **array** but I'm talking about **recursion** here.

Comment: @GhostCat : Thanks to mention that. But I just placed it for knowledge purpose as Eqra looks like new to Java. But I have updated as NOTE to not use that approach.

Comment: @Eqra Khattak  : Here in Java 8 approach we are converting it to List using Stream.  Which was added in Java 8. And as toString() method in List is overridden method, it will print the data. As array is of type primitive and List can be created of primitive, so we are casting it to Boxed Primitive long to Long.

Comment: @GauravJeswani I see.

Comment: @EqraKhattak And I cant see why you claim "they are different", when the answer you accepted, and the answer that is accepted on the DUP ... do the exact same thing.